# Powershell: Array to email To Field email Address

Tags: powershell, email, message

I am trying to send email to a list based on some parameter. A email should be sent to several groups based on filter "Operation Model"

I have the data currently look like this

```
foreach($opModel in $opModelarr){
    $filterOp = @($XLSfile |Where-Object {$_.'Operating Model' -eq $opModel.Name})
    $emailArray = @( $filterOp | Select-Object 'Email Address'|Get-Unique -AsString |% {[string]$_})
    echo $opModel.Name
    echo @(,$emailArray)
}
// Calling email Function
EmailNotification @(,$emailArray) $($MasterLogFile) $opModel.Name
```

The echo output looks like below

```
ROE
@{Server Owner=noopur@gmail.com}
@{Server Owner=riya@gmail.com}
@{Server Owner=noopur@gmail.com}
AOE
@{Server Owner=riya@gmail.com}
LOCAL
@{Server Owner=roshan@gmail.com}
FOE
@{Server Owner=akhil@gmail.com}
SOE
@{Server Owner=nidhi@gmail.com}
BLO
@{Server Owner=jaspal@gmail.com}
NGO
@{Server Owner=prashant@gmail.com}
```

Where AOE ROE LOCAL SOE BLO NGO are Operating Model and the Server Owner are email address where I need to send 1 email per Operating Model

Now I m pushing it to the email function which looks like this

```
Function EmailNotification ([string[]]$ToEmail, [string]$LogFileToAttach, [string]$OpModel){
    $emailServer ="myServer.gmail.com"
    $emailFrom = "NoReply-Junkey <no-reply@gmail.com>"
    $emailSubject = "Feedback from Automated Junkey Window for OpModel: $OpModel"
    $emailNotifyBody = "Hello <br> <p>Please find the feedback from Automated Email notification for the Junkey have. </p> <p>Do not Respond. On Issue reach out to @ for help.  </p> <p>Regards</p> <p>Automated Junkey Status</p>"
    Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $emailServer `
                     -From $emailFrom `
                     -To $ToEmail `
                     -CC 'anirban@gmail.com' `
                     -Subject $emailSubject `
                     -Body $emailNotifyBody `
                     -Priority Low `
                     -DeliveryNotificationOption None `
                     -BodyAsHTML
}
```

I am getting the following error

```
Send-MailMessage : Syntax error in parameters or arguments. The server response was: 5.1.3 Bad recipient address syntax
At D:\Junkey not reporting from past 30 days\JunkeyAutomatedEmail.ps1:24 char:5
+     Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $emailServer `
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

My Best guess is I am messing up the To Field in the email address and not able to handle the To field as expected by the Send-MailMessage. Please help

***EDIT:*** I am getting the unique values of email addresses - but only sending to only one email address per Operating Model instead of sending 1 email to multiple email address per operating model
ROE -> Operating Model. I am able to send only to one email address instead of all 3.

```
$opModelarr = @($XLSfile | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Operating Model' |Sort-Object -Unique)
    #echo $opModelarr
    foreach($opModel in $opModelarr){
        $filterOp = @($XLSfile |Where-Object {$_.'Operating Model' -eq $opModel})
        $emailArray = @( $filterOp | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Server Owner'|Sort-Object -Unique |% {[string]$_})
}
EmailNotification @(,$emailArray) $($MasterLogFile) $opModel.Name
```

Comment: Maybe `Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Email Address'` instead of `Select-Object 'Email Address'`?

Comment: Oh!! You are awesome. Thank You. Now I don't get the error and it sends email. Only Problem is For the Operating Model : ROE
@{Server Owner=noopur@gmail.com}
@{Server Owner=riya@gmail.com}
@{Server Owner=noopur@gmail.com} it is suppose to send 1 email to all recipient noopur riya and noopur again (don't know event after unique why 2 noopur is coming) but atleast there should be 3 recipient - it only send to noopur and not riya

Comment: `Get-Unique` returns unique items from a *sorted* list. Try `Sort-Object -Unique` ?

Comment: @JosefZ Nice. It is now properly identifying the correct and unique email address. The only problem that remains is for a Operating Model if there are more than one email address - like in case of ROE - example shared above it is only sending to one email address. I have no clue how to send 1 email to all the recipient with all of them in TO list

Comment: @JosefZ I am still stuck:(